# Listview Freeze with Textviews and Edit Text in one Row

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, freeze

Hi I am using freeze concept in listview,
Row contains Textview and Edit texts,If i change any Edit text it should update the other column Textview is it possible? Currenly i am using https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders  Android library

[image]

Here is my adapter class:

When i change the age in edittext i need to change height based on age input.

```
 public class FamilyNexusAdapter extends BaseTableAdapter {

            private final int[] widths = { 100, 100, 100 };
            private final float density;
            private Vector<ProductMasterBO> items;

            public FamilyNexusAdapter(Context context, Vector<ProductMasterBO> items) {
                density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                this.items = items;

            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return this.items.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 3;
            }
              @Override
            public View getView(final int row, int column, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                String headerString[] = { "column 1", "column 2", "column 3",
                        };


            if (row == -1) {

                        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                R.layout.item_table_header_first, parent, false);

                    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name))
                            .setText(headerString[column + 1]);


                } else{
                user= (UserMaster) items.get(row);


                if(column==-1){
                        txt=user.getuserName();
                                  ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name))
                            .setText(headerString[column + 1]);


                    }else if(column==1){
                        txt=user.getage()+"";

                                 EditText age = (EditText) convertView
                                .findViewById(R.id.age);
                        age.setText(txt);
    age .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                String ageString= s.toString();
                                    if (!qty.equals("")) {

    }}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                    int count, int after) {
                            }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                    int before, int count) {
    //i want to handle when i am trying to change age height should be change
                            }
                        }); 
                    }else if(column==2){
                        txt=user.getheight()+"";

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name))
                            .setText(txt);
                    }

    return convertView;
                  }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @nanoc In Freeze  getview structure---View getView(final int row, int column, View convertView,ViewGroup parent).    so it was called column by column.how can i update other view.

Comment: keep a reference to it

Comment: @Surya please share your adapter code

Comment: @PhanVănLinh i created my adapter extends BaseTableAdapter , I am using https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders library

Comment: @Surya ok but please share your adapter code

Comment: @PhanVănLinh added in post

Answer (score 0):

Use a `viewHolder` pattern and set the `tag` property of the `EditText` to refer the `TextView`.